# Visa for 6 year old

Tags: visas

We have custody of a 6 year old nephew from Ghana.  We intend to adopt him.The period of time for all of this to be done in over two years.  For the boys sake we need to be with him.  Can we bring him here on a 5 or 10 year multiple entry visa, have him stay for 6 months, leave for a weekend to Canada and return for another 6 months, until this process is complete.His father deserted him at birth and his mother does not want him. He is currently staying with his grandmother, he know my wife and I as his parents.  What do you recommend.

Comment: Your question is impossible to even begin answer because you don't reveal which country it is about. (And even so, it looks like it's more of a question for [expats.SE]).

Comment: Inferring from your mention of Canada that you are in the US, no, you cannot use a 5- or 10-year multiple-entry visa to bring him to the US indefinitely by making visa runs outside of the country.  Or at least it's a risky proposition that could be seen as an abuse of the system.  There may be a solution, though; I will do some research and may be able to post an answer in a day or two (too busy today, I'm afraid).

Comment: @Raja A Java You should consult an immigration lawyer

Comment: The country is Ghana, West Africa, My wife is a Ghanaian, I am American, I lived in Ghana for the better part of 10 years, we were married in Ghana, and now we are living in the states. All I want to do is bring him here, let him go to school until we can complete this adoption process. His grandmother is old and cannot keep this up for much longer.

Comment: The country is Ghana, my wife is Ghanaian, I am an American.  I lived in Ghana for the better part of ten years.  We were married in Ghana.  All I want to do is bring the boy here to the states to be with us, go to school, until this adoption issue is complete.  He is with his Grandmother, she is old and cannot keep this up for much longer.He has no one that cares other than us.  Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Have you looked at the [USCIS adoption information](https://www.uscis.gov/adoption/country-information/adoption-information-ghana)? It includes children for whom you have legal guardianship or custody and the [Hague Process](https://www.uscis.gov/adoption/immigration-through-adoption/hague-process) has to be followed.

Comment: It can be done. A couple in my church did something similar however it not the right thing to do. I **would not** advise you to do it because it can get complicated and even though his grandmother is old, you can pay a nominal amount for someone to be a caretaker for him in Ghana for the two years or so. I am Ghanaian so I know these things. The adoption process itself can get complicated. Consult a competent immigration attorney or commit to a lot of researc, the information is all out there.

Answer (score 3):

You should consult a lawyer, but let me give you a short answer.

**No you cannot legally do this.**

It is absolutely prohibited to use a visitor visa to live in the US, and that is exactly what you are trying to do. The brief departures make no difference. Being a minor makes no difference, and nor does being in the custody of a US citizen. Even when you have successfully adopted the child there are still steps to go through for them to legally reside in the US.

I know someone who attempted this, and when discovered he was banned from the US, despite having both a wife and a child who were US citizens. It took the intervention of a congressman to get him admitted again.